# Coalesce columns based on pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, coalesce

I have combined data sets in R, and each data set may use a different column name for the same data. I need to use a regular expression to identify the names of the columns I need to combine, and then run that list of column names through coalesce.

I know the proper regex expression to identify my columns, and I know how to manually write the column names into the coalesce function to combine these columns, but I do not know how to automatically coalesce columns identified with a regular expression.

```
sample = data.frame("PIDno" = c('a', NA, NA), "PINID" = c(NA, 'b', NA), "ParcelId" = c(NA, NA, 'c'))

PID_search = paste("sample$",grep("*PID*|*PIN*|*PARCEL*",colnames(sample),ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE),sep = "")

sample$PID_combine = coalesce(sample$'PIDno',
                              sample$'PINID',
                              sample$'ParcelId')
```

Answer (score 9):

We can use `tidyverse`.  The selected columns are converted to `character` with `mutate_at`, then `coalesce` those columns in `mutate`

```
library(tidyverse)
sample %>%
    mutate_at(vars(matches("PID|PIN|Parcel")), as.character) %>% 
    mutate(new = coalesce(!!! select(., matches("PID|PIN|Parcel"))))
#    PIDno PINID ParcelId new
#1     a  <NA>     <NA>   a
#2  <NA>     b     <NA>   b
#3  <NA>  <NA>        c   c
```

Comment: This works for me but I am not sure why the negation is needed in coalesce. I would expect it to be `new = coalesce(select(., matches("PID|PIN|Parcel")))`, but using something like that gives me the columns back unchanged.

Comment: @KevinMc It is not negation in the tidyverse.  The evaluation functions are `!!` and `!!!`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it.

- (a) Don't get `"sample$PIDno"` as a string - that's pretty useless. Just get the column names as strings.
- (b) We'll make a separate function that calls `coalesce` on all the columns in a data frame. This is nice and easy to write, and then we can...
- (c) Call the `coalesce_df` function on the subset of columns you want to coalesce. It's easy to subset a data frame based on a vector of column names, so we've simplified the first step, and added two additional simple steps to get the result.

With your sample data, the columns are all `factor`s with different levels. Can't coalesce those as-is, so I added an `lapply(..., as.character)` to convert everything to character first. If your real data isn't `factor` class, then you can skip that step.

```
cols = grep("*PID*|*PIN*|*PARCEL*",colnames(sample),ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)

coalesce_df = function(df) {
  do.call(coalesce, df)
}

coalesce_df(lapply(sample[cols], as.character))
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

If you want to make this work in a `dplyr` pipeline, I'd suggest something like this (or see akrun's answer for something a little more idiomatic).

```
sample %>%
  mutate_at(vars(one_of(cols)), as.character) %>%
  mutate(PID_combine = coalesce_df(.[cols]))
#   PIDno PINID ParcelId PID_combine
# 1     a  <NA>     <NA>           a
# 2  <NA>     b     <NA>           b
# 3  <NA>  <NA>        c           c
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be barking up the wrong tree, but the contract of the `coalesce()` function is that it returns the first non `NA` value in the parameter list, from left to right.  So, if you use the following code:

```
sample$PID_combine = coalesce(sample$PIDno, sample$PINID, sample$ParcelId)
```

then the behavior would be to first return `PIDno`, should that value be non `NA`, then `PINID`, and following `ParcelID`, in that order.

The value for `PID_combine` would be `['a', 'b', 'c']`, for the sample input data you gave in your question.

Comment: I could also be wrong, but I read the OP as wanting to somehow _dynamically_ pass the column names to `coalesce`.

Comment: The code given is not clear enough for me to be able to update my answer.