# How to coalesce chunks of columns based on a prefix pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that's comprised of several "chunks" of columns. In each chunk, the columns names are the same but distinguished by a prefix: `A_color`, `B_color`, `C_color`, `XX_height`, `YY_height`, `ZZ_height`, etc. Sometimes, there might be just the stem name without any prefix. Also, in each chunk there's only one column with data and the others are `NA`:

```r
######### CHUNK OF COLOR ########  ## ###### CHUNK OF HEIGHT #############
##   A_color B_color C_color color ## XX_height height YY_height ZZ_height
##   <lgl>   <lgl>     <dbl> <lgl> ## <lgl>     <lgl>  <lgl>         <dbl>
## 1 NA      NA            1 NA    ## NA        NA     NA               15
```

Therefore, I want to coalesce the chunks to get:

```r
##   color height
##   <dbl>  <dbl>
## 1     1     15
```

### Example

I've built a dumb function to simulate the structure of the data. Its internals don't matter, just the output.

```r
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

generate_data <-
  function(n_of_chunks, n_variants_in_each_chunk, nrows) {
    
    # helper func for later
    interweave_vecs <- function(x, y, n){
      c(x, y)[order(c(ceiling(seq_along(x) / n), seq_along(y)))]}
    
    # generate col names
    names_core           <- stri_rand_strings(n = n_of_chunks, length = 10)
    names_expanded       <- rep(names_core, each = n_variants_in_each_chunk)
    prefixes             <- replicate(expr = stri_rand_strings(n = 1, length = sample(1:3, 1)), n = length(names_expanded))
    names_with_prefixes  <- paste(prefixes, names_expanded, sep = "__")
    names_final          <- interweave_vecs(names_with_prefixes, names_core, n_variants_in_each_chunk)
    
    # generate data
    dat <-
      rerun(
      replicate(expr = sample(c(rep(NA, n_variants_in_each_chunk), runif(1))), n = n_of_chunks) %>% 
        as.vector() %>% 
        setNames(., names_final) %>% 
        bind_rows(), 
      .n = nrows
    ) %>%
      bind_rows() %>%
      cbind(., col_blah = rnorm(nrows), col_foo = letters[1:nrows])
    
    # shuffle columns
    dat[,sample(ncol(dat))] %>%
      as_tibble()
    
}
```

Now simulating the data:

```r
set.seed(2021)
my_df <- generate_data(n_of_chunks = 3, n_variants_in_each_chunk = 3, nrows = 10)
 
> my_df
## # A tibble: 10 x 14
##    v__RmiNdhdGoy s13__1pbZoFVrxX Qx8__1pbZoFVrxX RmiNdhdGoy col_blah Xe__8xOGZuvswo `8xOGZuvswo` A__1pbZoFVrxX w__RmiNdhdGoy col_foo WM__8xOGZuvswo `1pbZoFVrxX` SNr__8xOGZuvswo tYD__RmiNdhdGoy
##            <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
##  1       NA              NA               NA        NA        -1.50          NA           NA             0.846         0.763 a               NA           NA              0.0479          NA    
##  2        0.0729         NA               NA        NA         2.20           0.365       NA            NA            NA     b               NA            0.995         NA               NA    
##  3       NA              NA               NA         0.398     0.939         NA           NA            NA            NA     c                0.695        0.234         NA               NA    
##  4       NA               0.541           NA        NA         0.713         NA           NA            NA             0.235 d               NA           NA              0.470           NA    
##  5       NA               0.317           NA        NA        -0.805         NA            0.163        NA            NA     e               NA           NA             NA                0.506
##  6       NA              NA                0.991     0.0519    0.791         NA            0.888        NA            NA     f               NA           NA             NA               NA    
##  7        0.159          NA               NA        NA         0.116         NA           NA             0.223        NA     g               NA           NA              0.260           NA    
##  8        0.442           0.0561          NA        NA        -1.33          NA           NA            NA            NA     h                0.663       NA             NA               NA    
##  9       NA              NA                0.346     0.479    -1.82          NA            0.193        NA            NA     i               NA           NA             NA               NA    
## 10       NA              NA                0.443     0.469    -0.403         NA           NA            NA            NA     j               NA           NA              0.450           NA
```

In `my_df`, the columns are organized around 3 "stems":

- RmiNdhdGoy
- 1pbZoFVrxX
- 8xOGZuvswo

Each of which has 3 prefixed versions, and one version which is just the stem, so for example, the `RmiNdhdGoy` chunk:

```r
my_df %>% 
  select(ends_with("RmiNdhdGoy"))

## # A tibble: 10 x 4
##    v__RmiNdhdGoy RmiNdhdGoy w__RmiNdhdGoy tYD__RmiNdhdGoy
##            <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>
##  1       NA         NA              0.763          NA    
##  2        0.0729    NA             NA              NA    
##  3       NA          0.398         NA              NA    
##  4       NA         NA              0.235          NA    
##  5       NA         NA             NA               0.506
##  6       NA          0.0519        NA              NA    
##  7        0.159     NA             NA              NA    
##  8        0.442     NA             NA              NA    
##  9       NA          0.479         NA              NA    
## 10       NA          0.469         NA              NA
```

- The *prefix* itself is alphanumeric in length between 1-3 characters.
- The *separator* between prefix and stem is two underscores (`__`)

I'm trying to come up with a way that would go over column names, and for the ones that have two underscores, take the substring *after* that separator, and look for other column names that end with that substring, then consider all those as a chunk of columns and coalesce them.

### Desired output

I need to coalesce each chunk to get:

```r
## # A tibble: 10 x 5
##    RmiNdhdGoy `1pbZoFVrxX` `8xOGZuvswo` col_blah col_foo
##         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  
##  1     0.763        0.846        0.0479   -1.50  a      
##  2     0.0729       0.995        0.365     2.20  b      
##  3     0.398        0.234        0.695     0.939 c      
##  4     0.235        0.541        0.470     0.713 d      
##  5     0.506        0.317        0.163    -0.805 e      
##  6     0.0519       0.991        0.888     0.791 f      
##  7     0.159        0.223        0.260     0.116 g      
##  8     0.442        0.0561       0.663    -1.33  h      
##  9     0.479        0.346        0.193    -1.82  i      
## 10     0.469        0.443        0.450    -0.403 j
```

I've seen a bunch of SO posts about this topic (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776187/coalesce-columns-based-on-pattern-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271093/merge-multiple-variables-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60619814/coalesce-columns-with-capitalised-and-non-capitalised-versions-of-variables-name?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but I don't understand how those solutions fit my situation. I hope someone would have an idea. Thanks!

---

EDIT

---

Following @tamtam's answer below, I'd like to emphasize that the solution I'm looking for is for *any* output of `generate_data()`, and not specifically to `my_df`. I've showed `my_df` just to illustrate one exemplar data to tackle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extending the previous answer to remove the hard-coded column names and wrap a solution in a function:

```
transform_df <- function(start_df_, sep = '__'){
  
  # identify columns of interest
  spread_names <- grep(sep, colnames(start_df_), value = T)
  other_names <- setdiff(colnames(start_df_), spread_names)
  
  # grab the `key` part from their names
  spread_keys <- unique(
    sapply(
      strsplit(spread_names, sep)
      , `[[`
      , 2
    )
  )

  # apply the describe operation
  for(key in spread_keys){
    start_df_ <- start_df_ %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(!!key := coalesce(!!!select(., contains(key))))
  }
  
  # format and return
  start_df_ %>%
    dplyr::select(c(spread_keys, other_names))
}
```

and then you get the output

```
set.seed(2022)
my_df <- generate_data(n_of_chunks = 4, n_variants_in_each_chunk = 4, nrows = 10)
my_df %>% transform_df()
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   `098Wb7lVaq` oe7XBd42Mk TdFPA4qYnl qZQ8AvXzTl col_foo col_blah
          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
 1       0.0846      0.746      0.381     0.182  a         -0.583
 2       0.509       0.492      0.962     0.702  b         -0.198
 3       0.155       0.912      0.917     0.0141 c         -0.603
 4       0.998       0.603      0.121     0.943  d         -1.09 
 5       0.300       0.853      0.317     0.740  e          0.184
 6       0.0486      0.598      0.330     0.122  f          1.31 
 7       0.0583      0.757      0.650     0.465  g         -0.168
 8       0.819       0.461      0.165     0.597  h          0.344
 9       0.541       0.280      0.978     0.793  i          0.376
10       0.850       0.147      0.865     0.426  j         -0.195
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, it's great! Small thing though: how can we ensure that `grep(sep, colnames(start_df_), value = T)` matches *exactly* `sep == "__"` and not also `sep == "___" ` nor colnames that include more underscores?

Comment: I've tried adding a fixer to `sep` before it goes to `grep()`: `sep <- paste0("\\b", sep, "\\b")`, but it didn't work...

Comment: hi, `grep` uses regex-es, assuming the column structure you described above `sep = '[a-zA-Z0-9]+_{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]+'`, where `[a-zA-Z0-9]` would match letters / digits, `'+'` ensures that some of those letters / digits appear at least one time and `_{2}` matches exactly 2 underscores. Check `?regex` for more details. HTH

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `contains` function inside `coalesce` therefore you don't need to split the column names into *before _* and *after_*. Instead you are just looking for columns that have for example the word "RmiNdhdGoy" inside their name.

In short you tell R to create a new column based on all columns already including a certain expression.

```
df2 <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(RmiNdhdGoy = coalesce(!!!select(., contains("RmiNdhdGoy"))),
         `1pbZoFVrxX` = coalesce(!!!select(., contains("1pbZoFVrxX"))),
          `8xOGZuvswo` = coalesce(!!!select(., contains("8xOGZuvswo")))) %>%
  select(RmiNdhdGoy, `1pbZoFVrxX`, `8xOGZuvswo`, col_blah, col_foo)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   RmiNdhdGoy `1pbZoFVrxX` `8xOGZuvswo` col_blah col_foo
        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>  
 1     0.763        0.846        0.0479   -1.16  a      
 2     0.0729       0.995        0.365    -0.594 b      
 3     0.398        0.234        0.695    -0.583 c      
 4     0.517        0.632        0.432    -0.819 d      
 5     0.0462       0.652        0.213    -1.50  e      
 6     0.947        0.408        0.0811    2.20  f      
 7     0.495        0.0819       0.713     0.939 g      
 8     0.0151       0.459        0.0561    0.713 h      
 9     0.663        0.479        0.346    -0.805 i      
10     0.193        0.469        0.443     0.791 j
```

Comment: thanks. Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but I'm looking for a solution that is not bound to specific names. Every time you run `generate_data()` you get different column names and prefixes. So I need a flexible solution that could handle *any* output of `generate_data()`.

Comment: What is the `!!!` denoting here? Is there no wrapper function that allows using `contains()` directly within `coalesce()`? I stumbled upon `dplyr::pick()` page but the function doesn't seem to exist.