# Coalesce inside an across statement using column name and a prefix

Tags: r, dplyr, prefix, coalesce, across

Again I feel like I should be able to do something to seems not quite complicated but I can't figure it out.

I have a dataframe `df` with variables `a1, v_a1, a2, v_a2` and so on. All I want to do is `mutate` my dataframe so that `a1 = coalesce(a1, v_a1)`and `a2 = coalesce(a2, v_a2)`

I tried many different thing but keep it doesn't quite work yet.

Here is a toy example and things I tried :

```r
df <- data.frame(
  a1 = c(1,NA,2,NA),
  v_a1 = c(NA,0,NA,5),
  a2 = c(4,NA,8,NA),
  v_a2 = c(NA,7,NA,NA),
  a11 = c("just here","to force","the use of paste0","inside the coalesce"))
```

```r
df %>% mutate(
  across(c(a1,a2),
         ~ coalesce(!!!select(matches(paste0(cur_column(),"$"))))))
```

This throws an error about `cur_column()` which "Must only be used inside `across()`". I had the same error when first declaring a function with a df and variable parameters to wrap the coalesce but the it seemed not to appreciate the `.data[[cur_column()]]` inside the `across`

```r
df %>% mutate(
  across(c(a1,a2),
         ~ coalesce(across(all_of(c(cur_column(), paste0("v_", cur_column())))))))
```

This one doesn't have an error but the output is really weird turning the tibble into string and making some pasting. It puzzles me there.

This topic is veeeery close [How to coalesce chunks of columns based on a prefix pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503381/how-to-coalesce-chunks-of-columns-based-on-a-prefix-pattern) but the `coalesce` uses a raw string inside the `contains` which I don't have (hence the need for `cur_column` and moreover it uses a for loop while I think I should be able to do it within an `across`...but maybe not !

Any help or piece of advice much appreciated !

Comment: @jpsmith why did you delete your answer? It basically works?

Comment: missed the answer @jpsmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- purrr::map2_dfc(df[,str_detect(names(df),'\\ba1\\b|\\ba2\\b')], df[,str_detect(names(df),'v_')], ~ coalesce(.x,.y) )

df3 <- cbind(df2,df[,str_detect(names(df),'v_|a11')])


  a1 a2 v_a1 v_a2                 a11
1  1  4   NA   NA           just here
2  0  7    0    7            to force
3  2  8   NA   NA   the use of paste0
4  5 NA    5   NA inside the coalesce
```

with `across` please check the code below

```r
df %>% mutate(across(c(a1,a2), ~ coalesce(.x, get(paste('v',cur_column(),sep = '_'))) ))


  a1 v_a1 a2 v_a2                 a11
1  1   NA  4   NA           just here
2  0    0  7    7            to force
3  2   NA  8   NA   the use of paste0
4  5    5 NA   NA inside the coalesce
```

Comment: thank you @jkatam for the answer. it doesn't quite answer my issue because it does not use an across statement inside a mutate. so i know i can do it the way you do first coalesce all the variables i want with a for loop or a purrr:map and then cbind but this is not what i as looking for, if it's possible

Comment: @elka, as per your expectation, I updated the code to use across. Hope it helps

Comment: oooooh thaank you ! that's exactly what i wanted :) i missed the `get()` to avoid the error "Caused by error in cur_column(): ! Must only be used inside across()"

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't know why and how I did not find this yesterday, espacially as I tried with a custom coalesce function, but anyway, found something which works and is as easy as this :

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  a1 = c(1,NA,2,NA),
  v_a1 = c(NA,0,NA,5),
  a2 = c(4,NA,8,NA),
  v_a2 = c(NA,7,NA,NA),
  a11 = c("just","another","column","character"))

my_coalesce <- function(df,x){
  vx <- paste0("v_", x)
  return(coalesce(df[[x]], df[[vx]]))
}

df %>% mutate(across(c(a1, a2),
                     ~ my_coalesce(df=.data, x=cur_column())))
```

Although you need the function first to avoid the "Caused by error in `cur_column()`: ! Must only be used inside `across()`." issue